# How to add hidden field in form element in masterpage

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, master-pages, hidden-field

I want to add hidden field to every view i have through jquery or javascript. But i want that code to be in MasterPage.Master so i write code at one place and it adds on every view i have. Can i do this if yes then how? Im using asp.net mvc 2

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your master:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').append(
        $('<input/>')
            .attr('type', 'hidden')
            .attr('name', 'foo')
            .val('some value')
    );
});
```

or replace `$('body')` with some other selector to a placeholder you've put somewhere in your master page if you want this hidden field to be inserted in some specific position. You could also insert it into existing `<form>` by giving them some id or class (if you have more of them on the same page and you wanted to insert this hidden field in each form).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about MVC but in the master page `Page_PreRender` method you can have such code:

```
HiddenField field = new HiddenField();
field.ID = "HiddenField1";
field.Value = "SomeValue";
(this.Page.FindControl("form1") as HtmlForm).Controls.Add(field);
```

This will push the hidden field to the form regardless of what page is using the master page.

Comment: there are no such things as code behind events like `Page_PreRender` in ASP.NET MVC. In fact there is not even code behind :-). There are controllers, models and views.

Comment: @Darin OK, good to learn.. but still, doing it client side is the only option?